# Multimodule Maven Project with interdependencies?

Tags: maven, multi-module, maven-reactor

I have a top-level maven project with submodules. The first submodule is a Java project which generates some JavaScript library code from the compiler's annotation processor. I want to include those generated JS files into the second submodule, a webpack NPM managed project, for the build and then publish the webpack BACK into the first submodule before packaging into a fat-jar. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a circular dependency. You have to break this circular dependency. (You probably do similar things in your code all the time.)

I have solved the same problem by breaking up the Java project. Once you do that you will recognize that, in fact, your first project was serving two separate roles that then become separated:

From:

1. Java project with code and assembly
2. JavaScript project

To:

1. Java project with code
2. JavaScript project
3. JAR-packaged project with assembly

I've often seen this happen in multi-module projects that build into a WAR file, and I've adopted the rule of thumb that the WAR project should not have any Java (production) code, acknowledging its role as the aggregator/assembler.

Some folks will think this third project is frivolous, some always argue that you're easily getting too many Maven modules. I think that often stems from tooling or build pipeline limitations, once you break through those, you can just embrace a growing number of Maven modules, given that the boundaries are chosen well, and I see no problems here.

One hesitation, though: why is the JavaScript project separate to begin with? If it is not deployed separately (evidently it isn't since you're assembling the "fat-jar"), the JavaScript code is following the delivery lifecycle of the "fat-jar", which would benefit from being in the same source repository, so why even make it a separate Maven module? (If they were in separate source repositories, there's a cost in version management between the modules that I'm unsure you have reasons for.) There's no shame in having a monolith (if done well -- it happens, microservices make you believe otherwise, but in that world you'd probably deploy the JavaScript code separately anyway).